# Accessing the built request details in Karate

Tags: karate

Just like how the response information can be accessed through `response, responseHeaders` etc, is there any way to access the request information? I noticed that request information is not available through variables. Are there are any workarounds to access this information?

I understand that we build the request ourselves in the test scenario using the Given, When steps, so it may sound redundant. The reason I'm looking for this is I would like to access the complete request details Karate would've built using our test definition. The idea is to make this information available to a java class which can be called through the Java Interop. More specifically, I'm trying to build a swagger request and response validator to be used from karate.

The workaround I am using is to explicitly create variables like apipath and apimethod and use them with `path` and `method`. This does the job, but still one has to ensure that these variables are explicitly set. It will be cleaner if whatever request Karate built is just accessible through a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please raise a feature request. We can look at making this available as `karate.request` or similar.